# How to start a service by checking host group in inventory by using when statement

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Can some one help me to achieve below.

I have different groups in my inventory file of ansible. I need to execute few commands for one group and few for other group in a single playbook.

I have written playbook like below for single group execution and it is fine but i need to merge everything into single playbook.

```
---
- name: chekcing Service status
  hosts: hari
  tasks:
  - name : service status
    shell: systemctl status "{{item}}"
    with_items:
     - 'jboss_prod'
```

Can you please suggest.

Comment: so you need to do some other tasks in the second group?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please have a look at the formating guides on the editing page. Can you please format your code correctly ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask what is the goal of getting the service status with a direct command ? Although there are occasions where it might be needed, with ansible you usualy describe the state in an idempotent task (e.g. `state: started` for the `systemd` module), and then run it. The task will report `ok` if service is already up or start it (`changed`) if it needs to be, and even `error` in case it is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

For Different task on different group, you can write as below.

```
---
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
  - name : service status
    shell: systemctl status "{{item}}"
    with_items:
     - 'jboss_prod'

- hosts: host2
  tasks:
  - name : service status
    shell: systemctl status "{{item}}"
    with_items:
     - 'apache_prod'
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the systemd module as well for checking the service status. for eg: (from the ansible docs)

```
- name: Make sure a service is running
  systemd:
    state: started
    name: httpd
```